# Python - can not install some packages in latest version

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have installed 3.6.1 version of python interpreter. I have a project that need to use "PIL" library so I try to install it but it gives me error, "Error occurred when installing package 'PIL'". I search it out why it's happening and I think it can only be installed on lower version of interpreter 2.7 or something lower. Now how can I install PIL in 3.6.1 version of interpreter? Should I downgrade my interpreter instead? But if I do, can it cause some other packages to be unable to install for it is only for 3.X version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Pillow](http://python-pillow.org/) is a fork of PIL that works for python 3 and python 2

Comment: what is a fork? sorry do not really know. So I should use Pillow instead? Is it the same as PIL?

Comment: are tried in linux or windows? if ubuntu put your command you tried

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Im using windows OS. 7 specifically.

Comment: thats why asked... in window you need to download and install... check my answer it will be in detail

Comment: Install using `pip install pillow` and then in your script you can use `from PIL import xxxx`

Comment: Pillow works very similar to PIL and it can be installed in windows using pip `pip install pillow`

Comment: [Fork definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development))

Comment: for windows better download from unoffcial libraries site and install

Comment: Now my problem is "cv2". I can not download and install it directly from the compiler. I tried to install "opencv" then write "from opencv import cv2" but error in 'cv2' part. How can I import cv2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download pillow based on your version.  from python [unofficial library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) ..

search pillow choose your python version and distribution from it... once you download,
move onto download path or

```
pip install ~/Downloads/Pillow‑4.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Pillow, the packaged and maintained fork of PIL, using:

```
pip install pillow
```